# How to set Minimum time to appear as default in UIDatepicker everytime

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

In Datepicker i have set Min and Max time where uidatepicker can scroll for example i have set 3:00PM as minimum time and 8:00PM as maximum time , when i run the app i want the datepicker to display the Minimum time not the current time of the device . I have hard coded UIDatepicker in my project havent used in xib file . I have set Min time but when i switch from control.tag ==1 to 2 the minimum time changes and also when i open the app for first time the datepicker doesnt start from minimum time.

UPDATE :

```
-(IBAction)notificationButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control
{

    if (control.tag == 1)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

        [components setHour:7];;
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:11];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];

    }

    if (control.tag == 2)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

        [components setHour:12];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:17];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT:

```
int startHour = 7;
int endHour = 11;

NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date1];
[components setHour: startHour];
[components setMinute: 0];
[components setSecond: 0];
NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];

[components setHour: endHour];
[components setMinute: 0];
[components setSecond: 0];
NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];

[userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];
[userTimePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
[userTimePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];
[userTimePicker setDate:startDate animated:YES];
[userTimePicker reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: Are you asking how to incorporate the example into your code?

Comment: I have set the date but the datepicker doesnt start/display the minimum time

Comment: The above code I posted lets you set the hour, minute and second. For example if your minimum time is 8 then setHour: 8 setMinute: 0 setSecond: 0

Comment: ..in my code i have set min time as ` [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];`...but the datepicker isnt starting from it when i run the app

Comment: you don't have to use the INT.

Comment: Instead of using [components setHour: startHour] you can use [components setHour: 7];

Comment: @sangony....just one small query ..when the user changes time in datepicker .. how to display that particular time when the user selects datepicker IF the user has changed the time in datepicker .. i want to display that time when user wants to see datepicker

Answer (score 4):

For Swift version:

```
let startHour: Int = 6
let endHour: Int = 23
let date1: NSDate = NSDate()
let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let components: NSDateComponents = gregorian.components(([.Day, .Month, .Year]), fromDate: date1)
components.hour = startHour
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
let startDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)!
components.hour = endHour
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0
let endDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)!
datePicker.datePickerMode = .Time
datePicker.minimumDate = startDate
datePicker.maximumDate = endDate
datePicker.setDate(startDate, animated: true)
datePicker.reloadInputViews()
```

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for Swift 3 :

```
        let startHour: Int = 6
        let endHour: Int = 23
        let date1: NSDate = NSDate()
        let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!

        let components: NSDateComponents = gregorian.components(([.day, .month, .year]), from: date1 as Date) as NSDateComponents
        components.hour = startHour
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0
        let startDate: NSDate = gregorian.date(from: components as DateComponents)! as NSDate

        components.hour = endHour
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0
        let endDate: NSDate = gregorian.date(from: components as DateComponents)! as NSDate

        timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        timePicker.minimumDate = startDate as Date
        timePicker.maximumDate = endDate as Date
        timePicker.setDate(startDate as Date, animated: true)
        timePicker.reloadInputViews()
        timePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: (self.view.frame.height/2 + 60), width: self.view.frame.width, height: 150.0)
        timePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
//        timePicker.reloadInputViews()
        self.view.addSubview(timePicker)
        timePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RoundTripViewController.startTimeDiveChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Answer (score 2):

The UIDatePicker class has a `setDate:animated:` method that you can use to set the date to whatever date/time you want on the date picker instance.

More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006806-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 1):

```
datePickerObj = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 160)];
datePickerObj.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
datePickerObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[datePickerObj addTarget:self action:@selector(onDatePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Pass String into method and format to date...

```
-(void)Set_MinimumDate_ToDatePicker:(NSString*)Time //  "start_time" = "3:00PM";
{
    NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dformat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

    [datePickerObj setMinimumDate:[dformat dateFromString:Time]];
    [datePickerObj setDate:[dformat dateFromString:Time] animated:YES];
    [datePickerObj reloadInputViews];
}
```

While change the Picker, it convert time to UTC+00:00, But it displays time to your time Zone eg. India, it add UTC+05:30 to the Time. If any TimeZone problem set TimeZone to the **NSDateFormatter**.

```
-(void)onDatePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{
    NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dformat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSLog(@"%@",datePicker.date); //  2000-01-01 11:30:00 +0000
    [newStartBtn setTitle:[dformat stringFromDate:datePicker.date] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    //"05:00 PM";
 }
```