# Is it possible to disable infinite scrolling in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I need to create a UIDatePicker in Date mode that user cannot scroll the UIDatePicker infinitely. I have tried to set min and max date like in this link [How to disable infinite scrolling in UIDatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198769/how-to-disable-infinite-scrolling-in-uidatepicker)

Here the code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:2015];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps setYear:1914];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

but the UIDatePicker is still infinite scrolling, it just avoid the date out of min-max date. Is it possible to disable infinite scrolling in UIDatePicker?

Comment: can you please post some code

Comment: Where do you call this pice of code ? Make sure that the `maxDate` & `minDate` are actually set on the date picker. Try to print out the values from the `UIDatePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `maximumDate` and `minimumDate` is the only possibility to customize behavior of `UIDatePicker`. If it is not suits your requirements, you can create your own custom date picker, based on `UIPickerView` or find some 3d party, for example [that](https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker) at GitHub