# iOS Set datepicker TimeMode minimum and maximum date between PM and AM

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, datepicker

I have a UIDatePicker in Time mode, and I need to set a minimum and maximum time but it needs to be between PM and AM (11:00 PM and 02:00 AM).
I tried adding a day component `components.Day = 1;` but it doesn't see to work it get maximum date at midnight. Any thought to set multiple ranges or something to make it work ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to select the date as well, or just a Time?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322625/3231194

Comment: @rbaldwin i need only Time picker

Comment: @Glenn yes i tried that but same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @SeifSelmi I would suggest using UIPickerView with one component for your hour range and one for minutes.

Comment: If you chose time mode , `MaximumDate` must be great than `MinimumDate`, so you can set 2AM~11PM but can't reverse them.

Comment: @Cole yes you are right, I had to do that programatically and setting two ranges, and that fixed my problem.